# extracting the values inside an object

Tags: java, jpa

my current code

```
Object resultQuery;
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TESTPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
TypedQuery<Account> tp = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.email = :email AND a.pwd = :pwd AND a.role = 'admin'", Account.class);
tp.setParameter("email", this.username);
tp.setParameter("pwd", this.password);
resultQuery = tp.getSingleResult();
```

the result is stored in the `resultQuery` object, but i'm confused on how to extract the datas inside the object.

let's say I want to extract the column `name` inside the account table from the `resultQuery` object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the type of `resultQuery`. Given that `tp` is of type `TypedQuery<Account>` I would *expect something like:

```
Account result = tp.getSingleResult();
```

... at which point it's easy to get the name from the `Account`, presumably. For example:

```
String name = result.getName();
```

Is there any reason for `resultQuery` to be typed as `Object` instead of `Account` in your code?

I haven't used `TypedQuery` myself, but the [documentation for `getSingleResult()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#getSingleResult%28%29) certainly suggests this is the right approach.

Comment: oh man! i'm so dumb to use the result as an object. thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

In this case `tp.getSingleResult()` will return an `Account` object. You can assign (without any cast) the returned value to an `Account` reference.

Comment: This is more of a comment, than an actual answer.

Comment: And importantly, `resultQuery` is of type `Object`. The *value* of `resultQuery` is a reference to an object of type `Account`, but that's a different matter.